# My stoper doesn't start

Tags: javascript

In my code after click 'start ' I would like to see counting.

```js
var h = 0;
var m = 0;
var s = 0;

function stoper() {
  s++;
  if (s == 60) {
    s = 0;
    m++;
    if (m == 60) {
      m = 0;
      h++;
    }
  }
  refresh();
}

function refresh() {
  czas = h + ":" + m + ":" + s
  document.getElementById("czas").innerHTML = czas;
}
```

```html
<div id="czas">
  <button onclick="setInterval(refresh,1000)">Start</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I see you are using interval to measure seconds, minutes and hours. You should be aware that this is not an accurate way in JavaScript due to Throttling of intervals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Throttling_of_intervals

Comment: Thank You Mathus,
have an amazing day today ;-)

Comment: I think you mean to spell it _stopper_.

Answer (score 2):

You should call `stoper` not `refresh` : 
Like this :

```
<button onclick="setInterval(stoper,1000)">Start</button>
```